# JavaScript regexp parse date/time to milliseconds

Tags: javascript, regex, date, date-formatting

I need a little bit of help with a regular expression to convert a date into milliseconds using regular expressions.

I am not sure what regular expression I need to do this.

Here are a few example dates:

- *3 dagar, 12:00:46*
- *2 dagar, 8:01:00*
- *1 dag, 11:34:00*
- *0 dagar, 0:04:00*

Again, I'd like a regexp that will parse these dates into milliseconds.

Alternatively I could use a library like [this](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/date/), to parse the date. But I have not much experience with that either.

Comment: That's not a job for regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following regex captures days, hours, minutes and seconds.
I asume that you want the number of milliseconds since 1 Jan 1970 (epoch).
We initialize a Date object with the captured info and extract the milliseconds:

```
var regexp = /([0-9]*) [a-z]*, ([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*)/;
var match = regexp.exec('3 dagar, 12:00:46'); //insert your timespan as text here
var date = new Date(1970, 0, parseInt(match[1]) + 1, match[2], match[3], match[4]);
// var result = Math.floor(date.getTime()/1000); //seconds
var result = date.getTime() - date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000; //milliseconds
```

We also need to consider the timezone. The `date.getTimezoneOffset()` returns the offset in minutes.

Maybe you want to test this in [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/El7lNmYipT) and adjust because it may cause problems if the input does not comply with the format that you provided.

Comment: Thanks it sort of worked, I tried it on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/BH7OFWGR17) with another example date, and it worked aswell. However my expected result from the script you provided would've been 237 000 ms, but it gave me 2588637 ms which is Jan 31 1970 00:03:57 as a date.

Comment: If I open my browser console and type `var d = new Date(2588637); d` it gives me Jan 01 1970 09:11:26 GMT+0200. That's far from Jan 31

Comment: I used a epoch time converter tool on the web, which treated the number as seconds instead.

Comment: It now gave me -89763 which in seconds since epoch is equal to Dec 31 1969 00:03:57

Comment: I see now! It was because of the time zone. I edited my answer.

Comment: Well, now it gave me -86163 in seconds which is equal to Dec 31 1969 01:03:57, try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/0sjtohgy/

Comment: You forgot to add one day to day part. Here is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0sjtohgy/1/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61278/discussion-between-b0andrew-and-linus).